# Convert First Letter to Capital using String Template

Tags: java, antlr4, stringtemplate-4

I am using String template file to generate java files. For that i am using  ANTLR. Code for One of the string template file is shown below:

```
package framework;
public abstract class  Listener$GUIdriver.name$  {  
 $GUIdriver.commands:{ command |   
     public abstract void onNew$command.name;format="capital"$Command
           ($command.allParameter:{ param |   $param.type.name$ newValue};separator=" , "$);   
          }; separator="\n"$
$GUIdriver.allDataAccess:{ dataAccess | 
  public abstract void onNew$dataAccess.dataAccessName;format="capital"$Request(String request); 
     }; separator="\n"$
 }
```

But it doesnot produce effect of  `format="capital"`.How to incorporate such changes?Should i need to include any package or file?I am new to String Template & ANTLR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format string you want to use is "cap"

```
format="cap"
```

You'll need to register the StringRenderer first, however :-)

```java
stGroup.registerRenderer(String.class, new StringRenderer());
```

### More detail

Here's an example group file, `testGroup.stg`:

```
group testGroup;

test(text) ::= <<
<text; format="cap">
>>
```

and here's an example of using it:

```
import org.stringtemplate.v4.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        STGroup stGroup = new STGroupFile("testGroup.stg");
        ST st = stGroup.getInstanceOf("test");
        stGroup.registerRenderer(String.class, new StringRenderer());
        st.add("text", "helloWorld"); // note lower case 'h'
        System.out.println(st.render());
    }
}
```

This renders:

> HelloWorld

Comment: Can you please go through some hello world string template application where you can demonstrate me about how to use it ?

Comment: Sure, see my updated answer. For more info check the [ST docs](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ST4/StringTemplate+4+Documentation)

Comment: I have made changes in to String template file by registering the StringRendere. But prob is i cant change double to Double, i am able to change tempvalue to Tempvalue. Can you please give me reason ?

Answer (score 0):

```
method(item) ::= <<
<item.name; format="cap">Value
>>
```

Comment: Please consider adding commentary to your code in order to improve this answer.